# How many distinct video cards do I have?

Tags: nvidia, devices, graphics

I'm logged on to a remote machine and I'm trying to determine how many video cards are installed. The machine was built for CUDA operations so it's likely to have more than one NVIDIA card.

```
> lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
```

gives

```
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110GL [Tesla M2090] (rev a1)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110GL [Tesla M2090] (rev a1)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
83:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110GL [Tesla M2090] (rev a1)
84:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110GL [Tesla M2090] (rev a1)
```

Does this imply four different video cards? If so, are these the devices?

```
 > ls /dev/nvidia*
 /dev/nvidia0  /dev/nvidia1  /dev/nvidia2  /dev/nvidia3  /dev/nvidiactl
```

Comment: One, but you have a quad-core GPU.

Comment: @perror That's the kind of information I'm looking for. How can you tell from that output? I'll accept it if you turn it into an answer.

Comment: From the model, probably. However @ Wikipedia, the Tesla M2090 has only [one core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Tesla#Specifications_and_configurations) so it looks like you have 4 cards, which the distinct Bus IDs tend to confirm.

Comment: @Nasha so the distinct bus listed from `/dev/` suggest that there are four Telsa M2090 cards? Is that always true?

Comment: I don't know for sure as I never saw more than one display adapter of the same kind in a system but I'd trust the bus ID hence say «yes».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the nvidia case, it turns out that `nvidia-smi -L` does what I'm looking for:

> LIST OPTIONS:
>       -L,   --list-gpus           Display a list of GPUs connected to the system.

```
> nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: Tesla M2090 (UUID: GPU-29ca4022-cf9d-d39f-8c46-...)
GPU 1: Tesla M2090 (UUID: GPU-1e282221-0aac-9a10-a46c-...)
GPU 2: Tesla M2090 (UUID: GPU-5b912869-92d8-d599-7617-...)
GPU 3: Tesla M2090 (UUID: GPU-a6d833f2-18a2-7331-24bb-...)
```